# How do I split a string into a Multidimensional or a Jagged Array?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, variables

I have this:

```
String s = "abcd,efgh,ijkl";
```

I want to convert it into this programmatically:

```
String[,] s = {{"ab","cd"},{"ef","gh"},{"ij","kl"}};
```

The string can be of variable length. Can anyone tell me how do I do this?

Comment: Does it need to be a 2D array, or would `String[][]` work as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Splitting into `String[][]` can be done like this:

```
var res = s.Split(',')
    .Select(p => Regex.Split(p, "(?<=\\G.{2})"))
    .ToArray();
```

Converting to `String[,]` requires an additional loop:

```
var twoD = new String[res.Length,res[0].Length];
for (int i = 0 ; i != res.Length ; i++)
    for (int j = 0 ; j != res[0].Length ; j++)
        twoD[i,j] = res[i][j];
```

The 2D part requires that all strings separated by `,` be of the same length. The `res` array of arrays, on the other hand, can be "jagged", i.e. rows could have different lengths.

Comment: +1 nice! But you res is an array of array of length 3, not 2 (two strings and empty string).

Answer (score 4):

Do this

```
using System.Linq;

var s = "ab,cd;ef,gh;ij,kl";
var a = s.Split(';').Select(x=>x.Split(',')).ToArray()
```

or extension method

```
var a = "ab,cd;ef,gh;ij,kl".ToTwoDimArray();

public static class StringExtentions
{
    public static string[][] ToTwoDimArray(this string source, char separatorOuter = ';', char separatorInner = ',')
    {
        return source
               .Split(separatorOuter)
               .Select(x => x.Split(separatorInner))
               .ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: IMO this is the cleanest answer here

Comment: fantastic solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it with LINQ

```
 s.Split(',').Select(
             x => new string[2] { x.Substring(0, 2), x.Substring(2, 2)}
 ).ToArray();
```

or you can just go with cycle

```
        String s = "abcd,efgh,ijkl";
        var l = new List<string[]>();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i += 5)
            l.Add(new string[2] { s.Substring(i, 2), s.Substring(i + 2, 2) });

        String[][] sa = l.ToArray();
```